# Is this enough to detect race conditions?

Tags: c, linux, gcc

Say I have a multithreaded application and I run it with the **same inputs**. Is it enough to instrument every load and stores to detect write-write and write-read data races? I mean from the logged load and store addresses, if we can see which thread did which load and which thread did which store, we can detect write-read and write-write data race by noticing the overlapped addresses. Or am I missing something?

Comment: wouldn't the instrumentation automatically skew the results because it changes the runtime behavior?!

Comment: If it were this easy, I'm sure the problem would have been solved long ago.  Detecting is one thing; preventing is quite another.

Comment: duffymo: I am just talking about detecting at this moment.

Comment: A race condition doesn't have to involve write-read or write-write. Also, just because your test passes one time doesn't mean it will pass the next - there are a huge number of combinations that could happen.

Comment: You're proposing a check on *every* read and write?  That would be very inefficient, and it would also skew the results as it would change timing (i.e., the act of looking would change the behavior, as STATUS_ACCESS_DENIED mentioned).  There are also other types of race conditions.

Comment: If your threads are instead separate processes and have no access to each other's address space, you'll remove this kind of collision entirely at the cost of needing to pass data between processes when the data must be shared. Is this an option for your application?

Comment: Pubby: I said with the same input. Also assume here that all synchronization operations, signals etc. are logged and replayed exactly the same sequence each time.

Comment: @user1018562 If there are race conditions then they wouldn't be replayed in exactly the same sequence. (Oh, and use @ for comments as it sends a notification to the user)

Comment: Assume you identify interesting events as "startusing" (load) and "stopusing" (store or discard) and furthermore you can atomically assign a sequence# to these interesting events in your app, then you have enough data to determine whether your app *might* have races. Because every overlap is potentially a race, but only potentially. If the data is causally unrelated, then there is an overlap but no race. However, in C things are quite complicated. C compiler could order instructions such that what you think precedes the load, might actually follow, making it very hard to assign seq#.

Comment: @Pubby: I don't understand this. I know race condition wouldn't be replayed in exactly the same sequence. But at least by instrumenting each load and store, we can actually notice that for example memory at address 0x8000 was read by T1 and written by T2. You can say that the threads can execute different paths when run different times, but at least we will detect the racy variable that is responsible for divergence. Or not?

Answer (score 5, accepted):

> Or am I missing something?

You *are* missing a lot. As Pubby said, if you see read, then write in T1, and later read, then write in T2, you can't say *anything* about absence of races. You need to know about locks involved.

You may want to use a tool, such as Google's [ThreadSanitizer](http://code.google.com/p/data-race-test/wiki/ThreadSanitizer) instead.

Update:

> But will my approach cover all races or at least some of the races?

Your comments here and on other answers appear to show that you don't understand what a race is.

Your approach *may* expose *some* of the races, yes. It is guaranteed to *not* cover most of them (which will make the exercise futile).

Comment: C'mon, the guy provided a link.

Comment: @Employed Russian: I'm OK with false positives, that is race detected even if one is not there. But will my approach cover all races or at least some of the races?

Answer (score 2):

Here is a simple example from Wikipedia that I have slightly modified:

> As a simple example let us assume that two threads T1 and T2 each want
>   to perform arithmetic on the value of a global integer by one. Ideally, the
>   following sequence of operations would take place:
>
> 1. Integer i = 0; (memory)
> 2. T1 reads the value of i from memory into register1: 0
> 3. T1 increments the value of i in register1: (register1 contents) + 1 = 1
> 4. T1 stores the value of register1 in memory: 1
> 5. T2 reads the value of i from memory into register2: 1
> 6. T2 multiplies the value of i in register2: (register2 contents) * 2 = 2
> 7. T2 stores the value of register2 in memory: 2
> 8. Integer i = 2; (memory)
>
> In the case shown above, the final value of i is 2, as expected.
>   However, if the two threads run simultaneously without locking or
>   synchronization, the outcome of the operation could be wrong. The
>   alternative sequence of operations below demonstrates this scenario:
>
> 1. Integer i = 0; (memory)
> 2. T1 reads the value of i from memory into register1: 0
> 3. T2 reads the value of i from memory into register2: 0
> 4. T1 increments the value of i in register1: (register1 contents) + 1 = 1
> 5. T2 multiplies the value of i in register2: (register2 contents) * 2 = 0
> 6. T1 stores the value of register1 in memory: 1
> 7. T2 stores the value of register2 in memory: 0
> 8. Integer i = 0; (memory)
>
> The final value of i is 0 instead of the expected result of 2. This
>   occurs because the increment operations of the second case are not
>   mutually exclusive. Mutually exclusive operations are those that
>   cannot be interrupted while accessing some resource such as a memory
>   location. In the first case, T1 was not interrupted while accessing
>   the variable i, so its operation was mutually exclusive.

All of these operations are atomic. The race condition occurs because this certain order does not have the same semantics as the first. How do you prove the semantics are not the same as the first? Well, you know they are different for this case, but you need to prove every possible order to determine you have no race conditions. This is a very hard thing to do and has an immense complexity (probably NP-hard or requiring AI-complete) and thus can't be checked reliably.

What happens if a certain order never halts? How do you even know it will never halt in the first place? You're basically left with solving the halting problem which is an impossible task.

If you're talking about using consecutive reads or writes to determine the race, then observe this:

> 1. Integer i = 0; (memory)
> 2. T2 reads the value of i from memory into register2: 0
> 3. T2 multiplies the value of i in register2: (register2 contents) * 2 = 0
> 4. T2 stores the value of register2 in memory: 0
> 5. T1 reads the value of i from memory into register1: 0
> 6. T1 increments the value of i in register1: (register1 contents) + 1 = 1
> 7. T1 stores the value of register1 in memory: 1
> 8. Integer i = 1; (memory)

This has the same read/store pattern as the first but gives different results.

Comment: You haven't seem to understand my question. Here, if we instrument every load and store of thread 1 and 2, we would indeed see that T2 and T1 are writing to the same variable and thus detect a write/write violation. What is so difficult in this example? I'm OK with false positives too. I rather have a false positive than a race condition go undetected. I don't require a consecutive read write, I think having a read/write even separated by instructions is fine, to say its a race condition. We can ignore the parts of the code inside the locks. I think what I'm talking about is a viable approach.

Comment: @user1018562 I don't understand how you can determine which code is inside the locks (keep in mind that *code* shouldn't be locked but instead *data*) as that also requires solving the halting problem, and even if you could there are still chances for a race condition to occur.

Answer (score 1):

The most obvious thing you'll learn is that there are several threads using the same memory. That's not necessarily bad in itself.

Good uses would include protection by semaphores, atomic access and mechanisms like RCU or double buffering.

Bad uses would include races conditions, true and false sharing:

- Race conditions mostly stem from ordering issues - if a certain task A writes something at the end of its execution whereas task B needs that value at its start, you better make sure that the read of B only happens after A is completed. Semaphores, signals or similar are a good solution to this. Or run it in the same thread of course.
- True sharing means that two or more cores are aggressively reading and writing the same memory address. This slows down the processor as it will constantly have to send any changes to the caches of the other cores (and the memory of course). YOur approach could catch this, but probably not highlight it.
- False sharing is even more complex than true sharing: processor caches do not work on single bytes but on "cache lines" - which hold more than one value. If core A keeps hammering byte 0 of a line whereas core B keeps writing to byte 4, the cache updating will still stall the whole processor.

Comment: I already know these things. This doesn't answer my question.